# How do I use a dictionary to add a category column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, categories

So I have a dictionary:

```
dict = {'apple':'fruit', 'grape':'fruit', 'chickpea':'beans','coffee cup':'tableware'}
```

And I was wondering how to use it to make a new column that categorizes this dataframe with strings of text:

| Item | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| apple from happy orchard | 15 |
| grape from random vineyard | 20 |
| chickpea and black bean mix | 10 |
| coffee cup with dog decal | 14 |

Into something like

| Item | Cost | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple from happy orchard | 15 | fruit |
| grape from random vineyard | 20 | fruit |
| chickpea and black bean mix | 10 | beans |
| coffee cup with dog decal | 14 | tableware |

Any help would be appreciated!

I've made my dictionary, and I've tried

```
dict = {'apple':'fruit', 'grape':'fruit', 'chickpea':'beans','coffee cup':'tableware'}
df[category] = 'a'
df['category'] = df['Item'].map(dict)
```

but I don't know what to do with the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right path, it's just left with a few tweaks. You can use *apply* to map each item in the Item column to its respective category like this:

```
# Your dictionary
dict = {'apple': 'fruit', 'grape': 'fruit', 'chickpea': 'beans', 'coffee cup': 'tableware'}

# Your DataFrame
data = {'Item': ['apple from happy orchard', 'grape from random vineyard', 'chickpea and black bean mix', 'coffee cup with dog decal'],
        'Cost': [15, 20, 10, 14]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Mapping the 'Item' column to 'Category'
df['Category'] = df['Item'].apply(lambda x: next((value for key, value in category_dict.items() if key in x), None))

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data_customized={'Name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie'],'City': ['New York', 'San Francisco', 'Los Angeles'],'Age': [25, 30, 22],'Occupation': ['Engineer', 'Designer', 'Actor']
}

df_customized =pd.DataFrame(data_customized)

# Display the customized DataFrame
print(df_customized)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).